# Get sum of vales in column with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I want to get the sum of all the values in the column named numbers in table all_nums and store it into a variable. I tried below but it finds the number of rows.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
$STH_SELECT = $dbh->query("SELECT count(*) FROM all_nums");
$sof = $STH_SELECT->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsum.php

Comment: If you want the _sum_ of something, use a _sum()_ function. The clue is in the name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the sum of values you need to use sum and not count(*). Try this:

```
$STH_SELECT = $dbh->query("SELECT sum(numbers) FROM all_nums");
```

Answer (score 1):

public function GetBalance($username){

```
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT SUM(`balance`) FROM `users_table` WHERE `username` = ?" );
        $query->bindValue(1, $username);

        try{ $query->execute();   

        $total = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        $summ = $total[0]; // 0 is the first array. here array is only one.
        return $summ; 

        } catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
```

}